# How to handle classic load balancer with Elastic Beanstalk after redeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

We have an ELB which can scale up and down from 1 to 4 instances. When we deploy a new verison of the server it spins up a new instance.
Because we **need** 256 bit encryption on our HTTPS we've been forced to use the classic load balancer (the only one where we can force clients, in our case android and iphone apps). What we noticed is that the load balancer is strictly associated to a specific instance. So when the server is re-deployed then the load balancer stops working b/c the instance it was associated with does not exist anymore.

Is there any way to handle this? Or is there a way where we can use a application load balancer and still get 256 bit encryption?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [rolling updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rollingupdates.html) with Elastic Beanstalk. During an update a new instance will be added first. The new instance should be associated with the Load Balancer. When the new instance is up and running, the old one is stopped and removed from the Load Balancer. New instances should be associated with the Load Balancer automatically. If this doesn't happen, there must be something happening with your Elastic Beanstalk Environment.

You can definitely use 256 encryption with a [Network Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-nlb.html). You will have to terminate SSL at the EC2 instances.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I was looking into adding the termination into the instances instead. We have an extremely basic eb deploy setup where we have our config.yml and a bin directory where we but the application binary. When I read about .ebextensions they're supposed to go into the source bundle. How would one set up the eb configuration to deploy a source bundle instead and then be able to use those eb extensions.

Comment: Regarding the rolling update, the classic load balancer seems to be strictly associated to a certain instance. So when the new instance is up and running then that is a new instance which the load balancer has no idea about ..

Comment: 1) You can create a zip file with the .ebextensions folder and your source code and deploy this. You will also need a Procfile. Details depend on your environment. 2) I am pretty confident that EB can handle scaling in and out machines and the Classic Load Balancer will be updated. Try adding an instance (modify min capacity) to see what happens. The Load Balancer would be useless, if it couldn't handle this kind of updates.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But its the classic load balancer which they want you to migrate away from, so perhaps it is useless? When you configure it you point it to a specific instance and the instance we run now was created last time we deployed the server so the CLB didn't point to it ..

Comment: So I realized that I previously was manually adding the desired instance to the CLB. But now I instead go to the auto-scaling group and add the CLB to the auto-scaling group and then the instance is added automatically. Hope that will make it work for all my instances.